# How can I relabel my flash drive?

Tags: usb-drive

Currently it looks like:
 [image]

Comment: the disk utility answer is the safest ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

System - Administration - Disk Utility

click the drive - unmount the drive - change label and you're done!

mount again and everything is fine **beware don't change anything else or you can destroy all your data!**

Answer (score 7):

You can easily relabel your flash drive or your NTFS partition using gparted-partition manager.

Install Gparted:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Goto System-->Administration-->Gparted

Change the storage device to your Flash drive.A window will open,right click the partition and choose label to rename it.

[image]
**Note:**
 The arrow points to your storage device.By default it shows your harddisk paritions.Click there to change your storage device to your flash drive.
[image]
**Note:**
Right click on it and choose label and enter your new label there..

You can also check this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive)

Comment: GParted removes all the data on the partition on changing / creating partition label! Haven't you noticed that?

Comment: You need `mtools` installed, or GParted won't label the drive (for FAT32)

Answer (score 2):

For vfat (fat32) filesystem you can rename disk with:

```
sudo dosfslabel /dev/sdXY new_label
```

(where `/dev/sdXY` is partition you would like to rename)

If the filesystem is ntfs do:

```
sudo ntfslabel /dev/sdXY new_label
```

**Note:** device should to be unmounted first.