# Created bootable .iso on external USB HDD, how to get rid of it again?

Tags: live-usb, external-hdd, usb-drive

Using the guide on [ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook/get-ubuntu/download) I installed the image of the netbook edition on my external HDD using [Pendrive](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) on Windows. I was not aware that it would create such a mess and now want to get rid of it again, still retaining my old files. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the USB installer adds some files in the root folder of the USB disk and makes it bootable by adding some code in the Master Boot Record.

You can safely remove the files created by the USB installer using the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button.

You can restore (read: clear) the [MBR (Master Boot Record)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) using the following command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX count=1 bs=512
```

`/dev/sdX` is your USB drive, if you run `ls -l /dev/disk/by-label`, you will labeled partitions, e.g.:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 2011-03-04 22:58 ubuntu -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 2011-03-04 22:58 USBDRIVE -> ../../sdb1
```

Here, you can see that `/dev/sdb` is the external USB. If your partitions are not labeled, you could use `sudo fdisk -l` to get a list of partitions for each drive.

For relabeling the partition, you can use GParted, see [How can I relabel my flash drive?](https://askubuntu.com/q/12160/6969).

Comment: Okay, knowing that already helps because I did not want to lose any data. Is there anything more that I might have to perform? For example, the HDD was also renamed to "PENDRIVE", how do I revert that? Thanks a lot for your answer :)!

Comment: Are you using windows or Ubuntu right now?

Comment: Ubuntu of course ;) I only had to use Pendrive on Windows when I bought a new computer, and then replaced MS by Ubuntu

Comment: Updated with information about the MBR (optional) and the disk label.